# Чтение математического выражения

Tags: числительные, род

Как будет читаться "полтора" в математическом выражении х + 1,5?  Слово будет стоять в мужском роде?

Answer (score 1):

Чтение: "**икс плюс один и пять**". Более формально: "**икс плюс одна целая (и) пять десятых**". "Полтора" (как ссылка на число) возможно только в *неформальном* общении по поводу таких выражений. При этом, если единиц измерения нет, то "полтора" соответствует мужскому роду.

Answer (score 1):

Количественное числительное *полтора* имеет две формы именительного (и винительного) падежа — *полтора́* (мужской и средний род) и полторы́ (ж. р.): полтора литра, полтора бревна, полторы жизни.
Форма всех косвенных падежей (кроме винительного) — [полу́тора](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/), она сочетается с формой множественного числа последующего существительного.

Если в выражении нужно использовать именно "полтора", то произношение зависит от контекста (вопроса или задачи).

— Сколько стоит другая вещь?
— Вещь стоит икс плюс полтора рубля (м. р.).
[— Вещь стоит икс плюс полторы гривны (ж. р.).]